# how to count results in loop when loop.index not working

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an example of my query,
I want to generate a list and count each result but in this case loop.index does not work.

I saw some solutions but none of them solve it.

```
q = session.query(
         Post, User, Bookmark,
    ).filter(
         Post.id== Bookmark.post_id,
    ).filter(
         User.id == Bookmark.user_id,
    ).all()
```

jinja2 code

````
{% for item in q %} 
    {% if item[1].id == current_user.id %}  
        {{ loop.index }}
        {{ item[0].title }} 
    {% endif %} 
{% ```endfor %}
````

Comment: What do you mean "loop index does not work"?  What code did you try?

Comment: There is a lot, I will simplify:
{% for item in q %}
{% if item[1].id == current_user.id %}
{{loop.index}} {{ item[0].title }}
{% endif %} 
{% endfor%}

Comment: _"I saw some solutions"_ is irrelevant information unless you show them. If they don't work, then they are _not_ "solutions" in any case. However your attempts at solution might better explain your problem as it is entirely unclear.

Comment: Answer questions about the question,  and requests for more information or deficiencies in the question by editing the question, _not_ by posting important information in comments.  SO is not a discussion forum, it is a Q&A, you need to fix the question.

Comment: So the loop index counts the Posts there is 100+ / user chose 5 of them and bookmarked list will be like 1st post - #1, 2nd post - #23, 3rd post - #45 etc

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution - thank you for helping me

```
{% set ns = namespace(c = 0) %}


{% for item in q %} 
    {% if item[1].id == current_user.id %} 
        {% set ns.c = ns.c + 1 %} 
        {{  ns.c  }}
        {{ item[0].title }} 
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```